# UITableView with UISearchDisplay and Checkmarks

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I´ve got a TableView with a Searchdisplay and when the user tabs on a cell, the cell accessoryType toggles between none and checkmark. That works fine, when i´m using only the tableview. But when I select a cell while i´m using the searchdisplay, the selection won't be applied to the "normal" tableview.

Maik

Comment: When we are selecting cell, you can catch the data for that cell, and can compare in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method. Can you show your "
**didSelectRowForIndexPath** method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show me or tell me which type of data you are showing on table. and are you using a simple array? i have a method for solve this problem.

NOW i give you a tips when set chekmark you need to make changes in orignal array.How?When will you explain it. Then i can give you good method to do this.

Comment: i´m showning user-objects with some attributes like name and id and so on... the problem is, that there isn`t a property for selected or unselected... i think i´ve to change that

Comment: You are make dictionary for save attribute an user?

Comment: atm i´m checking which cells are selected when the user leaves the view

Comment: you need make a collection each user-objects. You should be use NSMUtabledictionary. and make an array of dictionary, set unique id for each dictionary.

Comment: Now i'm not free. i will send you a code. can chat with me after 3 hrs.

Comment: ah, thats a good idea... i think i´ll be able to do the rest on my own. thank you!